# finding height of the short ski ramp?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, foundations

[(link to question)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3H8Bg.jpg)

To find $x$, I could use trigonometry if I know the angle that's adjacent to 16 and opposite to $x$.

Is the angle for θ in the bigger triangle the same for the smaller triangle?

Comment: Do you know what "similar" triangles are?

Comment: @user296602 not really.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Note that the two triangle **are similar by AA test**. Please read about similarity [here](https://artofproblemsolving.com/ebooks/intro-geometry-ebook/preview).

Hence,

$$
\frac{x}{22}=\frac{16}{38}
$$

Thus,

> $$
> x \approx 9 
> $$